# Editing question after successful answer to better reflect the exact problem

Tags: discussion, edits

I just posted a question to SO asking why a thread in my python script was misbehaving.  I had some PySerial things included that turned out to not cause any bit of the problem, but I included that code because I suspected it might be interfering somehow with the threading libraries.

Since the PySerial part of the code had nothing to do with the problem I was experiencing, should I go back and edit my question so that it better represents the problem being solved?  I've seen a lot of answered questions where the asker posts an entire program, and I get impatient reading through all the irrelevant code to eventually find where the problem occurred.

On the other hand, perhaps the PySerial code is valuable to show that, in fact, it wasn't the problem?

Comment: Polishing your questions *is appreciated and appropriate*, regardless of it already being answered. Just make sure not to remove anything referenced in the answers, or otherwise relevant for answering.

Comment: Should I propose edits to other people's questions in these cases?